# Can I allow OpenFileDialog to return empty/blank filename?

Tags: c#, return, filenames, openfiledialog, string

I am looking for a way to force the *OpenFileDialog* to return *DialogResult.OK* in *ShowDialog*() even when the user left the *FileName* field of the dialog blank.

I mean, if the user clicks on "Open", I want to be able to process the *FileName* property whatever could be its value.

I know I can't inherit from *OpenFileDialog*, so, is there some method/property/event which I didn't spotted?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want the user to be able to leave it blank, rather than simply canceling?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: see my answer to Abbas.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, a user can't press the `Open` button on the dialog when no file is selected or when nothing is entered in the textbox for the filename. If you do not care about the field being blank or not, why bother at all to use the `DialogResult.OK`? Just show the dialog en when the user chooses `Cancel` the `FileName` field will be empty.

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
var result = ofd.ShowDialog();
var fileName = ofd.FileName;
```

**Update:**

If you do want a difference between `OK` and  `Cancel`, you can use following code:

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
var result = ofd.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Process FileName
}
else if(result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //Process empty string
}
```

**Update:**

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Select a file?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    var result = ofd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var fileName = ofd.FileName;
        //Do something with the filename
    }
    else if(result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        //Process 'Cancel': create file or show errormessage or ...
    }
}
else
{
    //Create file
}
```

Comment: Yea, of course I could do that but, I want my UI to look logic. `Cancel` here in my case, will really mean "cancel", and will not mean "empty filename".

Comment: Just joking but: `ofd.Title = "Select a file or click Cancel for an ampty filename.";`

Comment: @user3535021 What's the logic in using an OpenFileDialog if you're going to allow a blank path?

Comment: @Abbas people would actually have to read dialog titles for that to work =p

Comment: @Abbas: Lol... understandable but not really intuitive.

Comment: Too bad the OpenFileDialog doesn't have the `Description` property like the `FolderBrowserDialog` has. This is better visible than the Title property.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: Actually, the blank return would be a special case, where I would automatically create a new file with a default name.

Comment: I would rewrite my logic to solve this, check my updated answer

Comment: @user3535021 Not that it will solve your problem, but if you're using the path to save a file rather than open one, you should really use SaveFileDialog instead of OpenFileDialog

Comment: Sorry, Abbas, but I can't accept that logic. Because here, you won't process the canceling case. I mean the "real" cancelation.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: I will use this dialog to either read it when it exists, create it when it doesn't and create a default one when nothing specified. Finally all that matters is getting a filename or a cancelation.

Comment: @user3535021 Just my two cents but I think Abbas' answer probably makes the most sense in your case. To me, simply allowing a blank file name doesn't imply that the program will choose one for me. If I saw any kind of open dialog I would assume that I *must* pick a file.

Comment: Consider initializing the OpenFileDialog with your default filename and when the user clicks "OK" check if the file exists or not.

Comment: Well thank you all, you gave me nice creative solutions but I think **I need to reflect** a bit more on all this, and the logic behind. ATM, I'm on a something with a higher priority. I'll come back later but for my next question I will try to be a bit more explicit about my goal and the context.